# Extract text between specific string in a URL "/"

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I am trying to collect everything before a specific set of characters

i.e. I have a URL such as the following

```
url = "https://www.somewebsiteLink.com/someDirectory/Directory/ascensor/163235494/d"

url2 = "https://www.somewebsiteLink.com/someDirectory/Directory/aire-acondicionado-calefaccion-ascensor/45837493/d
```

I would like to extract two things from the links:

Link 1: `ascensor` and `163235494`
Link 2: `aire-acondicionado-calefaccion-ascensor` and `45837493`

So, the numbers between the last but one `/` and also the text between the last but 2 `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string on `/` and pull the 3rd and 2nd to last elements:

```
url = "https://www.somewebsiteLink.com/someDirectory/Directory/ascensor/163235494/d"
url2 = "https://www.somewebsiteLink.com/someDirectory/Directory/aire-acondicionado-calefaccion-ascensor/45837493/d"
urls = c(url, url2)

pieces = strsplit(urls, split = "/")
result = lapply(pieces, \(x) x[length(x) - 2:1])
## for older R verions:
# result = lapply(pieces, function(x) x[length(x) - 2:1])

result                
# [[1]]
# [1] "ascensor"  "163235494"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "aire-acondicionado-calefaccion-ascensor" "45837493"
```

Comment: I get the following error `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

Comment: What's your R version? If less than 4.1 the `\(x)` anonymous function syntax won't work, you can replace `\(x)` with `function(x)`. Otherwise, make sure you ran the code exactly as written. I copy/pasted it from R.

Comment: Thanks! yes, replacing `\(x)` with `function(x)` works.

Comment: I simplified a little bit, the `{}` aren't actually needed.